# Entity Framework 4: Can you duplicate an entity and alter it based on filter condition

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there a way within the entity framework designer to duplicate an entity and then apply a filter condition to both to make them unique. Id like to retain all navigation properties and what not.

For example, say in the database I had a table of orders. I could have two entities, one called `IncompleteOrders` and One called `Complete` based on the same table, with the complete having a filter specified on the database field 'complete'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is called **Table per Hierachy**

You have one physical table, which has a special, single, scalar column which is used as a **discriminator.**

Like this:

```
OrderId OrderName IsComplete
1       Foo       1
2       Bar       1
3       FooBar    0
```

Where **IsComplete** is the discriminator (BIT column, for example), so when you setup your entities on your EDMX, you create three entities:

```
1. Orders
2. CompleteOrders (derives from Orders)
3. InCompleteOrders (derives from Orders)
```

On the table mapping for Orders, you say "Maps to CompleteOrders, when IsComplete = 1", and "Maps to InCompleteOrders, when OrderType = 0".

Good writeup on TPH/Discriminator pattern [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/24/table-per-hierarchy-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx).